# Do Auditors use a specific methodology or framework when auditing IT Backup policy?

Tags: audit, backup

I am wondering if IT Auditors use a methodology or framework to audit a backup policy.

Here is a example of a different kind incase my question does not make sence:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
A programmer may use a methodology which refers to the 'Waterfall Method' in relation to their design/ approach.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: The simple answer is yes - auditors tend to use frameworks as it makes the work repeatable year-on-year and consistent. But I don't understand the rest of your question - can you provide more context.

Comment: I think in terms of IT ISO20001 is something which is tested against for management. I have found out that they follow a typical audit check list to test there systems.

Comment: What I meant was, what specifically are you asking for in your question? Examples of the types of frameworks? There are many!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the industry. Healthcare? Retail?

For instance, Healthcare has accreditation bodies like Joint Commission who primarily rely on HIPAA as a guide. Retail is expected to follow PCI standards to protect customer financial data (like credit card information).

Ultimately, all backup audits will typically look at several key concerns:

- backup frequency
- maximum Return to Operation time using current backup method
- Data retention policies

  - some industries require a minimum retention time
- Security of the backup media

  - physical security
  - offsite storage
  - encryption

Obviously, there may be other concerns, but those are the highlights.